# A vector space with topology generated by a family of typologies each makes it a topological vector space is a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $(\mathcal F_ \alpha ) _{ \alpha \in A}$ be a family of topologies on V, each of which turning $V$ into a topological vector space. Let $\mathcal F$ be the vector space generated by $ \bigcup_{ \alpha \in A} F_{\alpha}$. Show that $ (V,\mathcal F)$ is also a topological vector space.

---

I started by showing that $+ : V \times V \to V$ is continuous in $\mathcal F$. But I turned out suspiciously did not use the fact it is addition, i.e. I showed that any function $g : V \times V \to V$ that is continuous in all $ \mathcal F_ \alpha$ is also continuous in $\mathcal F$. I don't know if this conclusion is even true.

Anyone help me on this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to be answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/446432/4280 as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there finest topology which makes given vector space into a topological vector space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446386/is-there-finest-topology-which-makes-given-vector-space-into-a-topological-vecto)